# returning to place the FileInputstream had last left

Tags: java

I have read some data from a textfile using fileinputstream, when it reaches a certain area in the text file, the reading is stopped to do some other process[Say process A] (which uses the data read by fileinputstream till now). This new process which is started makes this fileinputstream to point to the end of file.

My question here is after the process A is completed how to return to the original place where the fileinputstream had left. I use Java version 1.7

Answer (score 2):

If you're bent on using a [`FileInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html), you can always use the [`mark`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#mark%28int%29) and [`reset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#reset%28%29) methods (if they're supported, that is).

However, you could also get a [`FileChannel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html) from [`FileInputStream#getChannel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#getChannel%28%29) (or a [`SeekableByteChannel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SeekableByteChannel.html) from [`Files#newByteChannel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newByteChannel%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...%29) if you want to use Java 7) and use [`position`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SeekableByteChannel.html#position%28%29) to get the position of the stream before process A and [`position(long)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SeekableByteChannel.html#position%28long%29) to reset the position of the stream after process A.